# Fonts Not working Properly In MAC Operating system browsers(Chrome and Safari)

Tags: fonts, cross-browser, webfonts

Here's the link for my site - http://thedesigningworld.com/united/

and here's the font family which i'm using - "Gotham-Book"

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Book';
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('fonts/Gotham-Book.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('fonts/Gotham-Book.svg#Gotham-Book') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It works fine in Firefox/chrome/safari Browsers under WINDOWS OS but not works in MAC OS.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this issue unfortunately by this method - I changed the font style from "Gotham-Book" to "GothamLight"

Answer (score 0):

On mac it is good with gotham-Light but still having issues with certain components like drop down. for those specific elements you can use some equivalent font family like  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; etc